# Decrement of end of std::map

Tags: c++, stl

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int , int > myMap;

    map<int , int>::iterator it;

    myMap.insert(pair<int , int>(1,2));
    myMap.insert(pair<int , int>(671,223));
    myMap.insert(pair<int , int>(353,245352));

    it = myMap.end() - 1;

    cout << it->first << it->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code produces the following compilation error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >}’ and ‘int’)
  it = myMap.end() - 1;
```

I don't know why I am getting this error as I think arithmetic operations are allowed in all types of iterators.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not all iterator categories support arithmetic operations, that's a misconception. If you aim to write more generic code, you can use [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
it = std::prev(myMap.end());
```

It expects a bidirectional iterator, which `std::map`'s iterator is. If you want to move the iterator more than a single step, it can also accept a second parameter that designated how far to move the iterator.

In addition, when you pass it a random access iterator, it will be as fast as the arithmetic.

Comment: error: ‘prev’ is not a member of ‘std’ , I am getting this error. Do I need some header file for that ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla - `<iterator>`

Comment: I included it , still getting the same error. Any other thing I have to add  ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla - Is your code built as C++11? You can use `std::advance` if you can't build it as such.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla `boost::prev`, then.

Comment: @Angew or, to avoid pulling in the whole of boost just for this, `it = myMap.end(); --it;`.  (But if you *still* can't use C++11, then I strongly recommend pulling in boost - for `boost::shared_ptr`, `boost::noncopyable`, and `BOOST_FOREACH` if nothing else.)

Comment: So basically, one could define `It& operator-(It& it, int n) { return prev(it, n); }`?

Comment: @YSC If one wants code which violates standard practices and thus scores poorly on the well-known code quality metric of "WTFs per minute," yes, one could. Plus it better be done with some heavy `enable_if`s to restrict it to iterators only, since templates like this are very greedy. Plus you cannot legally do it inside `std` where ADL could pick it up. In all, I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Angew I agree about the WTF^^, though no need to define this `operator-` inside `::std`: if `It` is a type inside `::std`, ADL would kick-in and find `std::prev`.

Comment: @YSC Yes, but being in the global namespace means that this `-` could potentially apply to *anything,* which is why heavy SFINAE is necessary. Otherwise, you could even get ambiguity between this `-` and the expected `-` applicable to random-access iterators.

Comment: What I am thinking is memory allocation in maps is not contiguous, i.e. why we can't do scalar operations on it.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla - Memory allocation doesn't have to be contiguous to support fast "random access". A skip list comes to mind.

Comment: You can also use `myMap.rbegin().base()`, which predates C++11. For OP's use, you don't even need the `base()` call

Comment: @Caleth `myMap.rbegin().base()` is `myMap.end()`.(but without base it's fine here)

Comment: @RiaD ah, good spot. Just using `auto it = myMap.rbegin()` is probably the simplest thing

Answer (score 17):

I recommend you read about the different [*iterator categories*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories), and learn what operations are available on them.

More specifically the [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) iterator is an [bidirectional iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) which doesn't have binary subtraction.